# Debugdiag on a .NET program - Leak Probability

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, debugdiag

I've very recently started working with .NET for the first time and have been tasked with locating a memory leak in a web-based program. After trying a variety of different methods and using a number of tools, I found Debugdiag and it seems promising. When I run it on a dump from the program, I get a lot of information that's difficult to decipher, but what catches my eye is segments like the following example:

```
Function           OraOCIEI11!ss_mem_alc+50b 
Source Line    
Allocation type    C/C++ runtime allocation(s) 
Allocation Count   139 allocation(s) 
Allocation Size    495.17 KBytes 
Leak Probability   95%
```

In particular, "Leak Probability" sounds like it would be relevant to my search. However, I'm unable to find an exact definition for it anywhere to know if I'm on the right track.

Does this mean that this function is extremely likely to cause a memory leak, being that its leak probability is so high? If so, how do I confirm it and how do I track down where it occurs?

Any help or direction would be appreciated!

Comment: The function name points to an Oracle library, but isn't of much help. Try looking for Oracle objects that are not properly disposed such as database connections, or even query parameters because they implement IDisposable.

Comment: Also, I suggest you use https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/ for profiling memory leaks.